# Conditionate expectation and characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y$ two random variables such that $X\sim \mathcal{E}(2)$ and $Y_{|X=x}\sim \mathcal{E}(x)$ for all $x>0$.

1. Find the density of $Y$.
2. Calculate $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq X)$.
3. Calculate the characteristic function of $XY$ and deduce its density.

My attempt is the following:

1. I find that:

$$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y|x)\cdot f_X(x)=$$

$$=xe^{-xy}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{(0,+\infty)}(y)\cdot 2e^{-2x}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{(0,+\infty)}(x)= $$

$$=2xe^{-x(y+2)}\mathbf{1}_{(0,+\infty)\times (0,+\infty)}(x,y)$$

So

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}2xe^{-x(y+2)}\ dx=\frac{2}{(y+2)^2}\mathbf{1}_{(0,+\infty)}(y)$$

2. I have no idea, I tried to use conditionate probability but doesn't work much.
3. $\varphi_{XY}(\theta)=\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta XY})=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta xY}|X=x)\right)=e^{i\theta x }\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta Y})=e^{i\theta x}\frac{x}{x-i\theta} $

and now I don't know how to do...Maybe, it's not the right way in this case

What's correct? Any suggestions for 2 and 3?

Comment: The law of total expectation says $E\left[e^{i\theta XY}\right]=E\left[E[e^{i\theta XY}\mid X]\right]$, and not what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is correct. For the second, you can notice that you have the joint distribution of $X,Y$, so it is simply integrating
\begin{align*}
P(Y \leq X) & = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x} 2xe^{-x(y+2)} dydx \\
& = \int_{0}^{\infty} 2 e^{-2x} - 2e^{-x^{2} - 2x} dx \\
& = 1 - 2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2} - 2x} dx \\
& = 1- 2e \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2} - 2x-1} dx \\
& = 1 - 2e \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(x+1)^{2}} dx 
\end{align*}
I'll leave it at that, and you can easily continue calculating that (Normal dist.). Now, for the 3, you can calculate directly
$$
\varphi_{XY}(t) = \iint_{(0,\infty)^{2}} e^{itxy} 2xe^{-x(y+2)} dydx
$$
Maybe there is another easier or different way, but this way everything comes out "directly"

Comment: All clear! But, in 3, is not there a way to use the conditional expectation? I try to use it to avoid the calculation of that integral

Comment: $\varphi_{XY}(\theta)=\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta XY})=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta XY}|X=x)\right)= \mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta xY}))= \mathbb{E}(\varphi_{Y}( \theta x)) $ . We would have to calculate the characteristic function of $Y$, but it looks complicated. You can look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269553/how-to-find-characteristic-function-of-product-of-random-variablesg

Comment: The density of $Y$ doesn't look good at all to do this calculation. Using the definition as you suggest me it's a better choice here

Comment: @daniel That's an incorrect application of the law of total expectation.

Comment: I got it! $$\varphi_{XY}(\theta)=\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta XY}| X\right)$$ So, for all $x>0$, I have $$\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta X Y} | X=x)=\mathbb{E}(e^{i\theta x Y} |X=x)=\varphi_{Y_{|X}}(x\theta)=\frac{x}{x-ix\theta}=\frac{1}{1-i\theta}$$ In definitive, because this is a constant, then $\varphi_{XY}(\theta)=\frac{1}{1-i\theta}$ and I notice that $XY\sim \mathcal{E}(1)$.